# SQL is only getting 1 row

Tags: php

I'm making a like system in php and I have a code to get all the usernames of the people who liked the post using the post id and if they haven't liked the post it will show a button that say like post and it if they haven't it will show a button that says unlike post and if there's no like it will say "No one has liked the post be the first". But when I add it in, it only get 1 user id even though multiple people have liked the post, how do I fixed this, here is my code:

```
$fancy = $db->fetch("SELECT * FROM " . $prefix . "_fancy WHERE post_id = '" . $post_row['id'] . "' ORDER BY id");

if ($fancy) {
    $name = $user->name($fancy['account_id']);
    if ($account['id'] !== $fancy['account_id']) {
        $fancytext = '<div>'.$name.' Like this post.<!-- BEGIN logged_in --> <a href="./?area=forum&amp;s=topic&amp;t='.$topic_id.'&amp;f='.$pid.'"><img src="./template/default/images/like.png" alt="" border="0"/></a><!-- END logged_in -->
</div>';
    } else {
        $fancytext = '<div>'.$name.' Like this post.<!-- BEGIN logged_in --> <a href="./?area=forum&amp;s=topic&amp;t='.$topic_id.'&amp;unf='.$pid.'"><img src="./template/default/images/unlike.png" alt="" border="0"/></a><!-- END logged_in -->
</div>';
    }
} else {
    $fancytext = '<div><i>No one has liked this post, be the first!</i> <!-- BEGIN logged_in --><a href="./?area=forum&amp;s=topic&amp;t='.$topic_id.'&amp;f='.$pid.'"><img src="./template/default/images/like.png" alt="" border="0"/></a><!-- END logged_in -->
</div>';
}
```

Comment: can you please at least describe the table? thanks

Comment: get rid of all that styling; it's not relevant and makes your code massive.

Comment: You have a `WHERE` in your query.  This might be your problem.  Are there more than one `$post_row['id']` in your array?  Have you echoed that array?

Comment: I see no loops here, yet you somehow state you want to show more than single account. How?

Comment: http://prntscr.com/15hhb7 here is the databse and when I try to look it I get an error Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'else' (T_ELSE) in /homepages/43/d456722778/htdocs/forum/core/topic.php on line 619

Comment: Hi Malik, what is `$fancy` containing after line 1? is that `$db-fetch(...` mysqli or PDO?

Answer (score 0):

Unleash the **power of PDO** with prepared statements and `fetchAll`:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM $prefix_fancy WHERE post_id = :pid ORDER BY id";
$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute(array(':pid' => $post_row['id']));
$posts = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Now `$posts` holds all your selected records. Use `foreach` to iterate.

Comment: Fatal error: Call to undefined method db::prepare() in /homepages/43/d456722778/htdocs/forum/core/topic.php on line 608